# How to assign a specific color to each hexagon plotted by geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom

I am trying to summarize a UMAP scatter plot of single cell sequencing data with hexagons. As the goal is to simplify very busy clustering results, I am mixing colors for each bin (=hexagon) according to how many cells of each cluster are in the bin. In other words, if there are 2 cells from cluster 1 and 8 from cluster 2, I mix the colors assigned to those clusters in the proportions of the cells.  This means I need to assign a specific color to each hexagon.

Please excuse the long code, I tried to shorten it as far as I could.

```r
library(hexbin)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

####################
# helper functions #
####################

#' Determines majority in a vector
#' @description 
#' Changed version of mclust::majorityVote. Ties are broken randomly.
#' 
#' @param x a vector
#' 
#' @returns 
#' A single element of x that has the highest count.
#' 
get_majority <- function(x){
  
  x <- as.vector(x)
  tally <- table(x)
  max_idx <- seq_along(tally)[tally == max(tally, na.rm = TRUE)]
  
  if(length(max_idx) > 1){
    max_idx <- sample(max_idx, size = 1)
  }
  
  majority <- names(tally)[max_idx]
  
  return(majority)
  
}



###################

# Toy data
umap_coords <- tibble( x = rnorm(1000),
                           y = rnorm(1000),
                           cluster = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 200))

colors <- c("#8DD3C7",
            "#FFFFB3",
            "#BEBADA",
            "#FB8072",
            "#80B1D3")
names(colors) <- 1:5

 
hexb <- hexbin::hexbin(umap_coords$x,
                     umap_coords$y,
                     xbins = 10,
                     xbnds = c(min(umap_coords$x),
                               max(umap_coords$x)),
                     ybnds = c(min(umap_coords$y),
                               max(umap_coords$y)),
                     IDs = TRUE)

gghex <- data.frame(hexbin::hcell2xy(hexb),
                      count = hexb@count,
                      cell = hexb@cell,
                      xo = hexb@xcm,
                      yo = hexb@ycm,
                      hexclust = NA)


for (i in seq_along(gghex$cell)){
    
    cell_id <- gghex$cell[i]
    hcnt <- gghex$count[i]
    
    orig_id <- which(hexb@cID == cell_id)
    umap_coords[orig_id,"hexbin"] <- cell_id
    
    gghex$hexclust[i] <- get_majority(umap_coords[orig_id, "cluster"])
    
  }
  
  
  hex_colors <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(gghex$cell))
 
  
  # For simplicity, here I assign a fixed color per cluster.
  for (n in seq_along(gghex$cell)){

    hex_colors[n] <- colors[names(colors) == gghex$hexclust[n]]
         
  }

  gghex$colors <- hex_colors


  # I define the data in the geom because I combine it with a scatterplot from a different data.frame.
  # (scatter plot is not relevatn for the question though.)
  p <- ggplot2::ggplot() + 
    ggplot2::geom_hex(data = gghex,
                      mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x,
                                             y = y),
                      fill = gghex$colors,
                      alpha = 0.8,
                      stat = "identity")

p
```

[image: wrong_fill]

However, the resulting plot clearly does not assign the colors to the correct hexagons. If I plot the clusters by assigning it inside of `aes()` I get a different picture:

```r
ggplot2::ggplot() + 
    ggplot2::geom_hex(data = gghex,
                      mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x,
                                             y = y,
                                             fill = hexclust),
                      alpha = 0.8,
                      stat = "identity")

p
```

[image: correct_automatic_fill]

Now, for this particular toy problem I can just assign the colors via `scale_fill_manual`:

```r
names(hex_colors) <- gghex$hexclust

ggplot2::ggplot() + 
    ggplot2::geom_hex(data = gghex,
                      mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x,
                                             y = y,
                                             fill = hexclust),
                      alpha = 0.8,
                      stat = "identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = hex_colors, guide = "none")
```

[image: toy_solution]

But remember, in my actual proplem, I have to assign *each* hexagon a specific color. And here geom_hex seems to break down:

```r
names(hex_colors) <- as.character(gghex$cell)

ggplot2::ggplot() + 
    ggplot2::geom_hex(data = gghex,
                                 mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x,
                                                        y = y,
                                                        fill = as.character(cell)),
                                 alpha = 0.8,
                                 stat = "identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = hex_colors, guide = "none")

p
```

[image: wrong_size]

As you can see the size of the hexagons suddenly is completely wrong. I read a short suggestion by Hadley to use `group = 1`  in `aes` to make the hexagons aware of each other, but this does not work for me either.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to get a working plot with geom_hex?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**
The answer by @Allen Cameron solves the question originally posed and I will mark it as the solution if there is no final answer to the edit.

However, I found that if I actually assign unique colors to the data, geom_hex once again produces hexagons of differing sizes:

```r
library(hexbin)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

####################
# helper functions #
####################

#' Determines majority in a vector
#' @description 
#' Changed version of mclust::majorityVote. Ties are broken randomly.
#' 
#' @param x a vector
#' 
#' @returns 
#' A single element of x that has the highest count.
#' 
get_majority <- function(x){
  
  x <- as.vector(x)
  tally <- table(x)
  max_idx <- seq_along(tally)[tally == max(tally, na.rm = TRUE)]
  
  if(length(max_idx) > 1){
    max_idx <- sample(max_idx, size = 1)
  }
  
  majority <- names(tally)[max_idx]
  
  return(majority)
  
}

#' Mixes the colors of two clusters proportionally.
#' 
#' @param df data.frame of cells with clusters in `color_by` and assigned 
#' hex bin in `hexbin`.
#' @param colors colors to be mixed.
#' @param cell Which hexbin to mix colors in.
#' @param color_by Column name where the clusters/groups are stored in `df`.
#' 
#' @returns 
#' Mixed color as hex code.
#' 
mix_rgb <- function(df, colors, cell, color_by){
  rgbcols <- col2rgb(colors)
  
  sel <- which(df$hexbin == cell)
  n_clust <- dplyr::pull(df[sel,color_by])
  n_clust <- table(as.character(n_clust))
  prop <- as.numeric(n_clust)
  names(prop) <- names(n_clust)
  prop <- prop/sum(prop)
  
  rgb_new <- sweep(rgbcols[,names(prop), drop=FALSE], MARGIN =2, FUN = "*", prop)  
  rgb_new <- rowSums(rgb_new)
  rgb_new <- rgb(red = rgb_new["red"], 
                 green = rgb_new["green"],
                 blue = rgb_new["blue"], 
                 maxColorValue = 255)
  return(rgb_new)
}



###################

umap_coords <- tibble( x = rnorm(1000),
                           y = rnorm(1000),
                           cluster = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 200))

colors <- c("#8DD3C7",
            "#FFFFB3",
            "#BEBADA",
            "#FB8072",
            "#80B1D3")
names(colors) <- 1:5

 
hexb <- hexbin::hexbin(umap_coords$x,
                     umap_coords$y,
                     xbins = 10,
                     xbnds = c(min(umap_coords$x),
                               max(umap_coords$x)),
                     ybnds = c(min(umap_coords$y),
                               max(umap_coords$y)),
                     IDs = TRUE)

gghex <- data.frame(hexbin::hcell2xy(hexb),
                      count = hexb@count,
                      cell = hexb@cell,
                      xo = hexb@xcm,
                      yo = hexb@ycm,
                      hexclust = NA)


for (i in seq_along(gghex$cell)){
    
    cell_id <- gghex$cell[i]
    hcnt <- gghex$count[i]
    
    orig_id <- which(hexb@cID == cell_id)
    umap_coords[orig_id,"hexbin"] <- cell_id
    
    gghex$hexclust[i] <- get_majority(umap_coords[orig_id, "cluster"])
    
  }
  
  
  hex_colors <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(gghex$cell))
 
  

  for (n in seq_along(gghex$cell)){

        hex_colors[n] <- mix_rgb(umap_coords,
                             colors = colors,
                             cell = gghex$cell[n],
                             color_by = "cluster")
  }

  gghex$colors <- hex_colors


ggplot2::ggplot() + 
  ggplot2::geom_hex(data = gghex,
                    mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x,
                                           y = y,
                                           fill = colors),
                    alpha = 0.8,
                    stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

The resulting plot looks as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to fill each hexagon according to the `color` column, you can use `scale_fill_identity`:

```r
ggplot(gghex, aes(x, y, fill = colors)) + 
  geom_hex(stat = 'identity') +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

We can see that all the colors are the desired ones and match the designated cluster by adding their cluster and color value as strings on the hexagons:

```r
ggplot(gghex, aes(x, y, fill = colors)) + 
  geom_hex(stat = 'identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(colors, hexclust, sep = '\n')), size = 2.5) +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

---

**Update**

For the edited version of the data, this is where the `group = 1` is needed:

```r
ggplot(gghex, aes(x, y, fill = colors, group = 1)) + 
  geom_hex(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Allan! This seems to indeed solve the problem for the example data I provided. However, when working on some actual data it only works partially. Some hexagons seem to still be of the wrong size: https://i.imgur.com/VEFUDUu.png Would you have any idea why that is?

Comment: @YumTum difficult to say without seeing the actual data I'm afraid.

Comment: I edited my original question, but if there is no solution to the update I will mark your answer as the correct one as it solves the original problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Although I obviously don't have the exact random data you used, I expect that the updated plot is not correct. I have seen this stripe pattern many times before (see also first plot of my question), although I am not sure why it is happening.

Comment: @YumTum this is a bug in ggplot which has been fixed in the latest development version. I didn't have the development version installed on my work PC. Now updated using `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2", force= TRUE)` - this looks more like the kind of thing you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, this indeed fixes the problem entirely now! This also explains why the previously functioning plot stopped working, I must have updated ggplot without being aware of it. Do you by any chance know a 'safe' stable previous version off ggplot one can use?

Comment: I checked and ggplot2 <= 3.3.0 or devel version (3.4.0.9000) work.